# Does the mining barge expert package allow alpha clones to fly these ships?

Tags: eve-online

Mining barges are locked ships for alpha clones. Not allowed to undock even if the required skills were learned during some earlier subscribed period of time.

With a purchase from the new expert system, though, an alpha clone may temporarily unlock access to mining barge required skills. Are alpha clones then able to undock a mining barge during the duration of their purchase?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. In this screenshot, the Mining Barge Operations Expert System has a ship unlock tooltip that confirms alpha clones can undock with the ship.

[image: expert skills show which ships are unlocked for alpha accounts in a tooltip]